# Change value of bound class on combobox change

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I linked a combobox SelectedValue to a class. I noticed, the class value is changed only when I exit the control.

How do I change this behavior and set the class value when the combobox SelectedValue is changed and has focus yet?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that your code is currently listening for the [SelectionChangeCommitted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectionchangecommitted?view=netframework-4.8) event? If so, give [SelectedIndexChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindexchanged?view=netframework-4.8) a try.

> The SelectionChangeCommitted event is raised only when the user changes the combo box selection, and you can create a handler for this event to provide special handling for the ComboBox when the user changes the selected item in the list. **However, depending on how the ComboBox is configured, and how the user changes the selected item, the SelectionChangeCommitted event may not be raised.** Alternatively, you can handle the SelectedIndexChanged, but note that this event occurs whether the index is changed programmatically or by the user.